# How to configure web proxy for Jing

Tags: configuration, proxy, jing

Jing is great. But it won't start unless it can phone the mother ship. My internet access is via corporate web proxy. Jing doesn't seem to offer any way of configuring its connection to the internet. You'd think it would just use the windows internet connection settings that work for browsing, but no dice.

Anyone solve this problem? Maybe there are some configuration files or registry settings that would fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that you figured out why yours wasn't working, but here is how to configure Jing to use a proxy. Just create a jing.exe.config file inside the c:\program files\techsmith\jing directory, and in it put:

<configuration>
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://proxy.you.com:8080" bypassonlocal="true" />
    </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
</configuration>

Replace the proxy address with yours, and you'll be in business.

Answer (score 1):

DOH!

Found out the real reason Jing is getting internet connection errors is that our company has blocked access to 'screencast.com'.

Never mind.